# How to get dynamic HTML page using C++?

Tags: c++, qt, chromium-embedded

I use Qt 4.8.x, Visual Studio 2010, 32bit Windows 7. I need to extract content from some web pages, so I've created GUI application and use `htmlcxx` library with `QNetworkAccessManager`. I don't need to show the page in any widget. It works fine for simple pages. But what should I use for dynamic pages?

For example, I've met Javascript code, containing `document.write()` calls and so on, which influenced on the result text content. Will `Chromium Embdedded Framework 1 (CEF 1)` help me in this cituation? If yes, which classes should be used? I'd like to grab pages in multithreaded way. And what about encoding? I have used FireFox heuristic engine in order to detect encoding before feeding `htmlcxx` with data.
I don't need a bloated solution with several fat dlls.

Comment: If you're using Qt, why not just use QWebKit?

Comment: Does QWebkit support all of these features: 1) Multithreading - should I feed QWebpage within GUI thread, while working with downloading in another threads. 2) Easy handling of external CSS files- for example, I need to know whether `form` has style `display: none` and CSS is not within html file. 3) Redirects - Do I have to handle them explicitly?